# Third party payment gateway integration with gravity forms

Tags: wordpress, gravityforms

how can i integrate a third party payment gateway with gravity forms?

I want it to redirect to the payment gateway after submit to pay there, I'm using https://www.payatrader.com/ as may payment gateway.

Answer (score -1):

As no add-on of Gravity Form is available for Payatrader payment gateway you will have to integrate using custom programming.

You can find documentation to integrate custom payment gateway in Gravity forms at below URL.

https://docs.gravityforms.com/gfpaymentaddon/

Hope this helps.

Comment: does this go to functions.php, I already read the link you gave i really dont understand how it works.

Ive emailed Gravityforms support and said i should use this,
https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_after_submission/
https://gravityplus.pro/gravity-forms-post-to-3rd-party/
but both doesnt work also

Comment: Yes, they have asked you to use functions which are called on form submission. I have shared in above answer the link which will help you to create custom add-on of payment gateway for gravity form.